# Validation rule, not correct AND statement

Tags: validation-rule

I have two validation rules, that are on the one object, but with similar logic.

The first rule:

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL(Status, "Completed"),

OR(
ISPICKVAL(WorkOrderCategory__c ,"Softener Installation"),
ISPICKVAL(OutsideTap__c,''),
ISPICKVAL(PRVFitted__c,''),
ISPICKVAL(DrinkingSupply__c ,''),
ISPICKVAL(NonReturnValve__c,''),
ISPICKVAL(DrainCompliance__c,''),
ISPICKVAL(StaticPressure__c,''),
ISBLANK(HACHTestNumberOfDrops__c),
ISBLANK(BypassLocation__c),
ISBLANK(InstalledLocation__c) )
)
```

The second Rule:

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL(Status, "Completed"),

OR(
ISPICKVAL( WorkOrderCategory__c ,"Accessory Installation"),
ISBLANK(InstalledLocation__c)
)
)
```

The problem is, that I'm updating the record, but it is not checking correctly, on what Work Order Category it is. When I'm on Softener Installation, all works fine, but when I'm on Accessory Installation, firstly, it shows, that I need to populate the Installed Location, what is correct, but then, it asks me to populate all the other fields, that are for Softener Installation, what is not correct. How can it be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

These two validation rules should really be more like 11 validation rules or so. While it's tempting to put all the fields you need in to one rule, this means users won't have an error message on the actual field they need to fill out. This is a bad UX, especially the first rule, where they have to work out which of ten fields they need to fill out.

As to your actual problem, the Work Order Category field should be part of the AND, not the OR:

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL(Status, "Completed"),
ISPICKVAL(WorkOrderCategory__c ,"Softener Installation"),

OR(
ISPICKVAL(OutsideTap__c,''),
ISPICKVAL(PRVFitted__c,''),
ISPICKVAL(DrinkingSupply__c ,''),
ISPICKVAL(NonReturnValve__c,''),
ISPICKVAL(DrainCompliance__c,''),
ISPICKVAL(StaticPressure__c,''),
ISBLANK(HACHTestNumberOfDrops__c),
ISBLANK(BypassLocation__c),
ISBLANK(InstalledLocation__c) )
)
```

---

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL(Status, "Completed"),
ISPICKVAL( WorkOrderCategory__c ,"Accessory Installation"),
ISBLANK(InstalledLocation__c)
)
)
```

The validation rule triggers when the result of the formula is true. Using OR means that "only one" needs to meet the condition, while AND means "all" the conditions need to be met.

As written, your first rule effectively says "if the status is completed, **and** any of these fields are blank, or Work Order Type is Softener Installation...", which is not what you meant, because if Softener Installation is selected, none of the other conditions matter, the OR is already true.

Your first rule, when fixed, reads "When the status is completed, **and** the Work Order Type is Softener Installation, **and** at least one of these fields is empty..."

Comment: The second rule doesn't work. The error should appear, but it saves without the error

Also, when I do the second rule as  AND(
ISPICKVAL(Status, "Completed"),
ISPICKVAL( WorkOrderCategory__c ,"Accessory Installation"),
OR(
ISBLANK(InstalledLocation__c)
)
) 

or change your option to OR - nothing.

Comment: Both of them not working

Comment: @Jekaterina Stop trying to use OR. It's not the proper use case here. Make sure the picklist values are correct.